# How to run a command from the terminal/a script without the need to wait until the program exits?

Tags: python, script, terminal, call

The problem is that if I execute a command (eg. a Python script), the terminal or script is waiting until the program return a exit status so that it can continue or return to terminal. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: You could run it in the background, just do: ./command.py &

Answer (score 3):

In most shells, you can launch commands or processes in the background by appending an ampersand (`&`) to the command:

```
python file.py &
```

Comment: Already tried this but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Several choices:

1. Run it in screen. `man screen`, `screen`, `myprorgamm`, `C-a d`, `screen -r`.
2. `nohup myprogramm`
3. `myprogramm &`

Comment: Tried: `$ screen _command_`, `$ nohup _command_` `$ _command_ &`. Nothing worked so far.

Comment: You need to start screen separately first; and if you don’t have screen, install it first.

Comment: for screen - start with `man screen`, it's complex app with lots and lots of functionality. `nohup` and `&` (aka detach) can't "not work", really. if there is any error - make sure to post it here.

Comment: Hey, the amperstand workaround is working, but for some unknown reason I must double-click on a terminal window because the new line does not show up for some reason. Solved, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you're using Bash or a similar shell, type:

```
./your_script.py &
```

Comment: Tried that from the terminal but it does not work.

Comment: What OS and shell are you using?

Comment: _Trisquel GNU/Linux_ with _dash_. In Terminal I am using _bash_, while in scripts _dash_. Either of these does not work. The command I am trying to execute is _/usr/share/screenlets/CircleClock/CircleClockScreenlet.py_ which is a part of a program called _Screenlets_ (also available in _Ubuntu_).